# Make div follow cursor on button click, and stop following cursor and go back to starting position on (another) button click

Tags: javascript, onclick, mouseevent

```
var bx = document.getElementById("movingbox");
var takeMeBtn = document.getElementById('takeMeBtn');
var letGoBtn = document.getElementById('letGoBtn');

function mouseMov(e) {
    bx.style.left = -50 + e.clientX + "px";
    bx.style.top = -50 + e.clientY + "px";
    bx.style.zIndex = -99;
}

takeMeBtn.clickToggle = function fn(e) {
    bx.style.left = -50 + e.clientX + "px";
    bx.style.top = -50 + e.clientY + "px";
    bx.style.zIndex = -99;
}


letGoBtn.onclick = function() {
    bx.style.position = "fixed";
    bx.style.top = 50;
    bx.style.left = 50;
}
```

Hey people!

I've been trying to get "movingbox" to move and follow the cursors positions, when I click the button "takeMeBtn".

But, it only places itself in the current position of the cursor, when the "takeMeBtn" is clicked, and then stays there.

I also want to make it go back to its starting position, or anyposition, when I click "letGoBtn", but I think I can manage that one on my own.

I do not want to use jQuery for this.

Superthankful for any help.

Comment: Can you provide us with actual working example please? You can use snippet feature to insert parts of your html and js and run it, so that we can help you out

Comment: Other than that, there are already answered questions on SO about following the mouse cursor. Yes, they use jQuery, but it shouldn't be a problem to "deconstruct" jQuery into vanila JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons need to activate a mousemove listener for whatever you want to track the mouse over, probably the `document` or `window`. Other than that, you were close. I used inline style, but obviously a separate css document is better outside of this narrow example.

```js
var bx = document.getElementById("movingbox");
var takeMeBtn = document.getElementById('takeMeBtn');
var letGoBtn = document.getElementById('letGoBtn');

function mouseMov(e) {
    bx.style.left = -50 + e.clientX + "px";
    bx.style.top = -50 + e.clientY + "px";
}

takeMeBtn.onclick = function(e) {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMov)
}


letGoBtn.onclick = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMov)
    bx.style.top = "";
    bx.style.left = "";
}
```

```html
<button id="takeMeBtn">click</button>
<button id="letGoBtn">unclick</button>
<div id="movingbox" style="width:30px; height:30px; border: 1px solid black; position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly! Thank you! I added a z-index property of -1 to the movingbox, to be able to click the put back button. ;)

Comment: Excellent! Also, I meant to fix the clicking issue with `pointer-events: none;`, but that didn't make it in there. Whether that or z-index works better for you here, it's a good thing to know going forward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

HTML:

```
<button id="takeMeBtn">take me</button>
<button id="letGoBtn">let go</button>
<div id="movingbox"></div>

var bx = document.getElementById("movingbox");
var takeMeBtn = document.getElementById('takeMeBtn');
var letGoBtn = document.getElementById('letGoBtn');
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

JS

```
// flag: div should/not move
let move = false;

// switch flag
takeMeBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  move = true;
});

// reset flag and position
letGoBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  move = false;
  bx.style.top = 0;
  bx.style.left = 0;
  bx.style.zIndex = 0;
});

// change its position on each mousemove event if the flag is set to true
document.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  if (move === true) {
    bx.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    bx.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
    bx.style.zIndex = -99;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, gonna check how this method works as well! I am sure I will learn something useful!